# Why fetchall always results in `None`?

Tags: python

Here are data in MySQL database：

python3 table：users_info

[image]

But when i use `fetchall` to get all data in tables it **always return none**!!

[image]

I really really dont konw how to fix it,can someone has met this problem?

the followings are the code files.

**encapsulation.py**

```
import MySQLdb

class mysql_encapsulation(object):
    def __init__(self,host,port,user,passwd,db,charset):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.db = db
        self.charset = charset

    def open(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.host,port=self.port,user=self.user,passwd=self.passwd,db=self.db,charset=self.charset)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def operate(self,sql,params):
        try:
            self.open()
            self.cursor.execute(sql,params)
            self.conn.commit()
            print(' operate ok')
            self.close()
        except Exception,e:
            print(e.message)
            self.conn.rollback()

    def get_result_set(self,sql,params=[]):
        result=None
        try:

            self.open()
            self.cursor.execute(sql,params)
            result = self.cursor.fetchall()
            self.close()


        except Exception,e:
            print('error!')
            print(e.message)

        return result
```

**use.py**(problem in this file)

```
#coding=utf-8
from encapsulation import *

mysql = mysql_encapsulation(port=3306,host='localhost',user='root',passwd='mysql',
                           db='python3',charset='utf8')

sql='select id,name from users_info where id=3'
result=mysql.get_result_set(sql)
print (result)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10584605) and improve your question.

Comment: @ruohola The rule of thumb on SO is to avoid posting the images of your IDE or stuff like that unless the question is *directly related* to the IDE. SO is not created to solve your own problems. If you post something then do it for **the whole community**. One may be unfamiliar with your IDE. I strictly recommend you to follow [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10584605) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens in this method;

```
def get_result_set(self,sql,params=[]):
    result=None
    try:
        self.open()
        self.cursor.execute(sql,params)
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.close()
    except Exception,e:
        print('error!')
        print(e.message)
    return result
```

One of the first 3 lines in the `try` block (`self.open / self.cursor.exec / result = self.cursor.fetch`) generate an error, which you are then catching in the `except` block and (you can see that it prints "error!"). That's why the `result` always stays in it's default `None` value. Remove the `except` block and it will tell you what kind of error occured.

You should almost never catch the bare `Exception` but instead catch specific kinds of exception and handle each of them correctly, this problem is a prefect example why.

The error in question probably happens because in your SQL query you are selecting `id` and `name`, when the columns in your table are actually `id` and `user_name`. So your SQL query should be like this;

```
sql = 'select id, user_name from users_info where id = 3'
```

Comment: An exception must eventually be caught. Better instead of removing the *try* / *except*, replace `print(e.message)` with `print(e)`, as the *message* attribute seems to be empty.

Comment: @CristiFati the interpreter WILL catch the exception anyway, if no one else in the call stack did. The proper way is to _only_ catch the one you can actually handle at this exact point - and to add a catch-all handler at the application's top-level for the others so you can 1/ log it somewhere with the full traceback (for debugging purpose) and 2/ display a more user-friendly error message and eventually let him retry the action etc. The OP's exception handler is actually more than useless, it's plain harmful.

Comment: well，first ，sorry for my mistake. i have changed the 'name' to 'user_name' and i even use 'select * from users_info' ,unfortunately it is still ‘None’

Comment: I am going to delete the 'except' to look which specific error it will be

Comment: uhhhh...  when i restart my VMware  everything worked well  ! Even don't need delete the 'except' thx a lot .  Your advise that don't use except i will remember it

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your sql statement? Based on your table your columns are "id", "user_name" and "passwd", but in your sql you are searching for "id" and "name", and "name" isn't a column so that will throw an error. Change your sql to "sql='select id,user_name from users_info where id=3'"

Comment: First, sorry for my mistake and i have changed the 'name' to 'user_name' and it still don't work. But when i restarted my VMware it worked！ I don't know what to say,because  before restart it i even use 'select * from users_info' and it is still 'None'~~ thx a lot bro!

Answer (score 0):

As ruohola already explained in his answer, your exception handler is hiding all the important informations about what *really* went wrong - FWIW, there's the "Error !" string printed in your screen capture just above the `None`. The point is: your try/except block is not only useless, it's actually harmful - it prevents some other code up the call stack to even be aware that there was a problem (and eventually solve it), it also prevents *you* from knowing what went wrong.  As a general rule, only catch exception the exact exception that you expect AND can effectively handle at this point in the code - if you can't fix the error at this point, let the exception propagate and let the calling code deal with it. Also, you want to have as few code as possible in your `try` clause (the only exception being the application's top-level exception handler of course).

This being said, there is indeed a very valid reason for wanting to be warned of exception, which is to make sure you free resources (and eventually rollback a transaction), but then you want 1/ to use a `finally` clause for resources cleanup (a `finally` block is *always* executed, whatever happens) and 2/ for the rollback part, use an except clause but *re-raise the exception*, ie:

```
# leave this one out of the try block - 
# there's nothing you can do here about a connection error
# so let the calling code deal with it
self.connect()

try:
    self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
except Exception as e:
    self.connection.rollback()
finally:
    # this will ALWAYS be executed (unless `self.connect()` raised
    # but then you don't even want to close the connection <g>
    self.close()
```

wrt/ the real cause of your problem, Kurose's answer is certainly the right one.

Also, there are a quite a few other things that are debatable with your "mysql_encapsulation" class ([the naming](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to start with but let ignore this ATM), the main one being to open and close the connection for each query. Opening a database connection has a rather high cost, so you want to keep it opened as long as possible (and eventually reconnect if you get a "2006 mysql has gone away" error).

Comment: Thanks for your advice('Opening a database connection has a rather high cost'), it's helpful and i will remember it forever. I wrote code in this way because i am a newt in python ...